# Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'EntryDate' at row 1

Tags: c#

i added a Datetimepicker to my winform which should insert date and time upon user selection to database column Entry Date but i get above error any help would be appreciated.

```
private void btnSubmitClients_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pigen"].ConnectionString;

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

        //     try
        {

            string CmdText = "INSERT INTO t_pi_Clients(ClientCode,ClientName,PostalAdd,Telephone,Fax,EntryDate,EmailAdd1,EmailAdd2,EmailAdd3,Website,TotalDeposit,AccountBal,ChargeRate)VALUES(@ClientCode, @ClientName, @PostalAdd, @Telephone, @EntryDate, @Fax, @EmailAdd1, @EmailAdd2, @EmailAdd3, @Website, @TotalDeposit, @AccountBal, @ChargeRate)";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(CmdText, connection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientCode", txtboxClientCode.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientName", txtboxClientName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostalAdd", txtboxPostalAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", txtboxTelephone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fax", txtboxFax.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdd1", txtboxEmailAddress1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdd2", txtboxEmailAddress2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdd3", txtboxEmailAddress3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Website", txtboxWebsite.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalDeposit", txtboxTotalDepo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountBal", txtboxAccountBal.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChargeRate", txtboxChargeRate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntryDate", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));

            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is No need to Conversion

Try this

```
DateTime dt=new DateTime();
if(DateTime.TryParse(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString(),out dt))
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntryDate", dt);

}
```

[**STOP Using ADD With Values**](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: i still got the same error and entry date datatype is set at datetime in database

Comment: @galaxybomb use debugger and check whether `dateTimePicker1.Value` contains date or not??

Comment: i used debugger and yes it contains date but in format {1/1/2015}

Comment: and if i change datatype of database to timestamp with default value as current time it works

Answer (score 0):

first try to put it in `DateTime` and then give the value to `parameter`

This will help you ....

```
 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
```

with the time component as a 24 hour clock. (i.e. the hours digits provided as a value between 00 and 23.)

MySQL provides a builtin function `STR_TO_DATE` which can convert strings in various formats to `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes.

So, as an alternative, you can also specify the value of a `DATETIME` with a call to that function, like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE('12/21/2012 1:13:58 PM','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

So, you could have MySQL do the conversion for you in the INSERT statement, if your VALUES list looked like this:

```
...  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@EntryDate', STR_TO_DATE(dateTimePicker1.Value,'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p');
```

Comment: can you debug what result contains ?

Comment: result also contains date and time in format {dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss}

Comment: is there any security concerns if i parse datetimepicker1 as Text cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntryDate", dateTimePicker1.Text); cos this also works with datatype timestamp

Comment: which database you are using and what datatype of the column ?
and no any security reason but it is always recomanded to save date in datetime format @DB level

Comment: you can refere to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt6y6733(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: mysql database with entrydate column which has datetime datatype i cant get value from datetimepicker into it

Comment: @galaxybomb just be careful while giving quotes. just concat the value of datetimepicker in that function and debug it to check what is getting inserted

Answer (score 0):

i did a thorough code check and realized my insert statement with column and values e.g `"INSERT INTO t_pi_Clients(ClientCode,ClientName,PostalAdd(..)VALUEVALUES(@ClientCode, @ClientName, @PostalAdd(...)` did not match the arrangement in my database so i did a rearrangement of my insert statement and used `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntryDate", dateTimePicker1.Value);` and it worked with my datatype datetime. tanx @POHH for your time you guys rock